# Why does font-size set on body tag not overwrite the one set on an element?

Tags: html, css

I'm loading an HTML page in an iframe and trying to set the font-size to 27pt to the body of iframes. but it does not apply that font to all the elements.

Below is the DIV and it's CSS:

```
<div id="d10" class="fnt12 page2parttext">COLLECTION</div>

.fnt12 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: MyriadPro-SemiExt;
  color: white;
}
```

And I'm applying this CSS to the body of the page:

```
font-size: 40pt !important;
```

Although in the developer tool, the font-size property for `.fnt12` is strikthrough but the text size is still 25px in size. I tried to uncheck the checkbox against `font-size: 25px` in Chrome Inpector and it worked.

Whats the problem? Why it does not overwrite the existing CSS property?

Comment: "Why it does not overwrite the existing CSS property?" -- Because they target different elements, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
* {
   font-size:25px;
}
```

Setting it in the body won't work, as font-size is usually no inheritable attribue*. (font-color and font-family are). But you can set your divs and other things to:

```
div {
   font-size:inherit;
}
```

then it will take the font-size from it's *direct* parent.

*bad wording, see here for more information: http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa073007.htm

Comment: what makes you think `font-size` isn't inherited by default?

Comment: The point with `px` is that _if_ you set the size in pixels _then_ the parent's size no longer matters. That is perfectly expectable.

Comment: Note that the rule you're suggesting will most likely be the least specific one, and completely ignored.

Comment: Yes, it is the least specific one. And depending on what the tc will achieve, it might be worthless. However font-size is inherited (by default) by using computed values. See also here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa073007.htm 
It is inheritance, yes - but not in the way one might expect it.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because you are applying the rule to the `body` element. While your font settings will inherit, if you apply a font setting directly to a child element that will generally override that applied to the parent. While the `!important` declaration will indeed give precedence to the styles to which it is applied in the body, importance does not cascade down to children. This is a good thing, because `!important` is generally only used for fine-tuning on a specific element or collection of elements.

For the official spec on specificity see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html.

And here is a general article on the topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.